# npm not able to install ibuilder

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (exec-npm-install) @ utilities ---
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/ossui-builder
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'ossui-builder' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'utilities'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (exec-npm-install) on project utilities: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

I am getting this error while downloading with node
Please suggest as how can I solve this?
I am Using 32 bit-- 6.11.2 for Windows 10

Comment: try removing your node_modules folder and then run `npm i`.

Comment: Didn't worked.
btw npm i gave
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\rez\REZ101\package.json'
npm WARN REZ101 No description
npm WARN REZ101 No repository field.
npm WARN REZ101 No README data
npm WARN REZ101 No license field.

Comment: @Rez D'Souza Can you please specify the command you are running